# T-SQL Unique Constraint WHERE AnotherColumn = ParticularValue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Consider a link table with the following columns:

```
PersonID int NOT NULL
LocationID int NOT NULL
Active bit NOT NULL
...
```

The system allows each Person and Location to be configured independently.  Once configured, each Person can be linked to at most one Location.  If a Person moves to a new Location, the link is to be deactivated, not deleted, so that the system knows when the Person was last linked to a particular Location.  A Person can have any number of inactive links, but at most one active link.  A Location can have any number of Persons actively linked to it.

How would I add a constraint to this table to prevent a second active link from being created for a Person when one already exists?

Edit: I thought this was a 2008 box... turns out it's 2005, so filtered indexes won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constraint for only one record marked as default.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637894/constraint-for-only-one-record-marked-as-default)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997837/unique-constraint-controlled-by-a-bit-column/3997883#3997883

Comment: if you look at the answers on the questions I've posted, you'll see that you can do a "poor man's" filtered index on earlier versions, using an indexed view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an indexed view to implement a "filtered index" on versions of SQL Server predating 2008:

```
CREATE VIEW vOnlyOneActive
AS
  SELECT PersonID
  FROM <underlying table>
  WHERE Active = 1
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_vOnlyOneActive on vOnlyOneActive (PersonID)
GO
```

You'll need to have the right [ANSI settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) turned on for this.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than a linking table, have a link to Location ID on the Person table, as SilverSkin suggests.  Now, if you want a list of inactives, add a trigger to the Person table to insert into a history table (a modification of your linking table) every time the location is changed (<> the last history table entry / one does not exist for the person).  The link in the Person table gives the active link, while the history table gives the history and (should a person ping-pong between locations) an indication of the history of locations rather than a list of inactives.

Comment: I like your idea.  Unfortunately, I'm stuck with the schema I've got.  :)

Comment: More's the pity. I like it, too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Constraints do not work across multiple rows, so you will need an [INSERT/UPDATE trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to enforce only one active record for a group of records with the same `PersonID` and `LocationID`.

Comment: I've not used triggers before... what/what kind of trigger would be best to use here?

Comment: When you write that trigger make sure you make it so it can handle multiple row inserts or deltes, triggers do NOT process one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

foreign key references from tblPerson to PersonID, from tblLocation to LocationID, and a joint key on PersonId and LocationId to make sure that they are unique together.

Comment: With just that, there could still be two rows with the same PersonID, different LocationIDs, and both Active = 1, which should not be allowed.

Comment: True. Then you might consider adding the locationId and active bit to the person table, which only allows one location per person...

Comment: That would do the constraining job.  But then the system would not have a record of the last time a Person was linked to a Location, which is also a requirement. :)

Comment: That depends, if you set locationActive = 0 on a person, you would still have the location info until the next time. Ah, I see, you still want to save the inactive links? Right, gotcha.