# Constraint for bit value in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, constraints

Assuming I have a table as such

```
[StockBarcodeID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[UserID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[StockID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[UnitPrice] [money] NOT NULL,
[Barcode] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
[IsDefault] [bit] NOT NULL,
[LastUpdated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

How would one go about creating a constraint that allows for only 1 Default barcode row per stockid?

I cant seem to get my head around this one. Is this a unique constraint or a check constraint?

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL Unique Constraint WHERE AnotherColumn = ParticularValue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097484/t-sql-unique-constraint-where-anothercolumn-particularvalue) (And there are further links in that question to yet *other* questions covering similar ground)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constraint for only one record marked as default.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637894/constraint-for-only-one-record-marked-as-default)

Comment: I apologize as it appears you are correct and this is a duplicate of the other questions. Problem is everyone has their own way of wording the question and hence the duplicates... If you wanna close feel free. Sorry again :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view which shows only the default barcodes. Then create a unique index on this view.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.DefaultBarcode
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT StockID, Barcode
    FROM dbo.Barcode
    WHERE IsDefault = 1
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UC_DefaultBarcode ON dbo.DefaultBarcode (StockID)
GO
```