# SQL unique contraint if a column is set to x

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, unique

is there a way in SQL to create the constraint that a column has to be unique, if a specific column has a specific value?

Example: the rows are not really deleted, but marked as 'deleted' in the database. And within the 'not-deleted' rows, ValueA has to be unique:

```
ID    ValueA          ValueB            Deleted
-----------------------------------------------------
1     'foo'           10               0
2     'bar'           20               0
3     'bar'           30               1
4     'bar'           40               1
5     'foo'           50               0 --NOT ALLOWED
```

I thought of something like a CHECK constraint, however I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with MySQL as it doesn't allow partial indexes

Comment: You may use filtered indexes. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997837/unique-constraint-controlled-by-a-bit-column) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

with SQL92 this is not possible, may be you could implement something with a trigger

Comment: is it possible to create a trigger that only checks if a 'constraint' is violated? i thought that it can only change data...

Comment: I don't know about "standard ansi" which is no indication of what MySQL can do (plus and minus from SQL92), but I would have stated that MySQL can't do this with CHECK since it parses but doesn't even implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the design a little bit?

It seems to me that you have a list of "thingies".  For each ValueA, there's a single active "thingy" at any one time.  This can best be modeled as follows:

1. Remove ValueA and Deleted from your main Thingies table.
2. Create a new table ActiveThingies with columns ValueA and ID.  Protect this table by making ValueA a unique or primary key.  (You may also need to make ID unique as well depending on whether a single ID can represent more than 1 ValueA).

Now, use the ActiveThingies table to control which record is current at any time.  To change the active (non-deleted) record for "foo", update it's ID column in ActiveThingies.

To get your list of non-deleted items join the two tables.

With this design, however, you will lose the ability to remember the ValueA for "deleted" "thingies".  If you need to remember those values, you will also need to include the ValueA column in Thingies.

Comment: That's a good idea. I need the ValueA for the deleted thingies, so in the InactiveThingies table I could have the same structure as in the ActiveThingies. And if I need information from both tables I can make a SELECT UNION, right?

Comment: No, I think you're missing my point.  ALL the items _stay_ in the "Thingies" table.  The ActiveThingies table is only a helper, and it's strictly limited to the ID and ValueA columns.  It exists only to help specify which items are not deleted (because that low cardinality Deleted column isn't such a great idea) and to make sure there's only one non-deleted ActiveA at a time.  All the data columns stay in Thingies.

Comment: Dividing the storage into two separate, almost-identical tables would also work.  But that kind of duplication of structure is _usually_ not a good idea.

Comment: I would not really duplicate the rows. I'd rather move them from my ActiveThingies table to the DeletedThingies table. So there would not be any duplicated row. The id in DeletedThingies would have to be the same as it was in the ActiveThingies... I need the ID and ValueA in both data sets because of some application-specific reasons.

Comment: I understand, but that's not the solution I'm suggesting.  In general, it's a bad idea to have two tables that contain the same kinds of entities.

Answer (score 1):

There is workaround this problem - create another column **deleted_on**
     `deleted_on timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`
and make unique key on both **ValueA** and **deleted_on**
    `UNIQUE KEY not_deleted (ValueA, deleted_on)`
When soft deleting a record insert `NOW()` for value of `deleted_on`

Comment: This is a great workaround, actually you can use nulls on the deleted_on column and that would work as well... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL ignores CHECK constraints, so you cannot do this in MySQL as you might in another database.

Here is a hack.  Unique constraint on valueA + deleted.  When deleting rows you cannot use just 1, they must be 1, 2, 3...

This at least lets you do it server-side in MySQL, but introduces a step.  When marking a row for deletion, you have to first go find the max(deleted), add 1, and plug that value in when marking for deletion.

Comment: unfortunately in the real table, the "deleted" column is more like a status column which accepts more than two values. however only one is the deleted-status. so just counting the deleted rows is not really an option. but thanks anyway :)

Comment: NEVER do that.  A column called "deleted" holds deleted.  Period, end of conversation.  Put the other status in another column.  Columns are free.

Answer (score 0):

Split your table into two tables: One which has a UNIQUE constraint on ValueA and one that doesn't.  Use a view+triggers to combine the two tables.  Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE _Active (
    ID       INTEGER,
    ValueA   VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
    ValueB   INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE _Deleted (
    ID       INTEGER,
    ValueA   VARCHAR(255), /* NOT unique! */
    ValueB   INTEGER
);

CREATE VIEW Thingies AS
    SELECT ID, ValueA, ValueB, 0 AS Deleted FROM _Active
UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, ValueA, ValueB, 1 AS Deleted FROM _Deleted;

CREATE TRIGGER _trg_ii_Thingies_Active
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Thingies
    FOR EACH ROW WHEN NOT NEW.Deleted
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO _Active(ID, ValueA, ValueB)
        VALUES (NEW.ID, NEW.ValueA, NEW.ValueB);
END;

CREATE TRIGGER _trg_ii_Thingies_Deleted
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Thingies
    FOR EACH ROW WHEN NEW.Deleted
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO _Deleted(ID, ValueA, ValueB)
        VALUES (NEW.ID, NEW.ValueA, NEW.ValueB);
END;

/* Add triggers for DELETE and UPDATE as appropriate */
```

(I'm not sure about the CREATE TRIGGER syntax, but you know what I mean.)

Comment: That's a good idea. Hoewver, I'm afraid that Triggers can't be connected with views in MySQL.