# Add Constraint Check for UK between a Value of a Column and other Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my target Table

```
T1
(
Id int not null PK,
Name nvarchar(10) not null
Flag bit not null
)
```

I need a Constraint check for check that in every row with same name just one row have a true flag, in other words I need a UK for (1-True value of flag , 2-Name), same names can have a false flags but just one of them can have a True flag. Does any one know about this script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UNIQUE constraint controlled by a bit column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997837/unique-constraint-controlled-by-a-bit-column)

Comment: (And many others - the surprising thing is how many ways people find to ask this question without stumbling upon the existing ones)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: we need a better unique identifier for questions and answers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a filtered unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON T1(Name) WHERE (Flag = 1)
```

Comment: How  Can I do it in Alter Table Script?

Comment: @dotNetist -  You don't. Filtered indexes are created using `CREATE INDEX` not `ALTER TABLE`